# Warning : comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: string, pointers, warnings

```
struct smt{
char *c;
};



int main(){
   char *w="astring";
   if(smt->c == w[0])
   ...do something
}
```

How do I fix the warning that I get in the if and what exacly causes it?

Comment: Read your `if(smt->c == w[0])`, read the error message, and you should understand :p

Answer (score 1):

The warning shows up because you're comparing `smt->c`, which is `char*`, to `w[0]`, which is a character (that for this comparison gets implicitly casted to `int`).

You probably meant comparing the first character like this:

```
if(smt->c[0] == w[0]) { ... }
```

If you want to compare full strings, use

```
if(strcmp(smt->c, w) == 0) { ... }
```

or even better, use [strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/) if you know the maximum length the strings can have.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the fact that often (almost always), you **don't want to** compare an adress (pointer) with a character.

You're comparing a char* c with a char 'a'. What you want to do is this I believe:

```
struct smt{
    char *c;
};



int main(){
   char *w="astring";
   // Here smt->c returns a char*
   // w[0] gets you the first character, so 'a'
   if(strcmp(smt->c, w) == 0)
   ...do something
}
```

If you want to compare the first characters of both strings, you have to add `[0]` to smt->c